# Surveys regarding popular UX questions

Tags: discussion

@Erics brought up a good idea in the UX chat. I'm not sure if he was serious or not, but either way, I saw it and thought it was a great idea.

Would anyone be interested in the findings if I were to run surveys in decent-sized numbers (hundreds to thousands) of people, and publish them on my blog, and then we could reference them on future UX questions about the subjects?

Some examples could be for icons, we could give out surveys where there's icons such as the hamburger (three lines), magnifying glass, and tens of other ones, and see if people can identify what would happen if you clicked that button. This would answer questions such as "how many people know that the hamburger icon means menu?"

I'm currently going to school in Toronto, and I have classes on 2 campuses, and I live on residence on another. Therefore I go through 3 campuses daily, and have a large pool of candidates if I were to hand out surveys. I pass by or otherwise see so many other students, it's unreal.

This question of the hamburger is only an example, and could be a first. We (I say we because it doesn't only have to be me, if we had a wide array of data we could pool it all together) could do several surveys over time, asking popular UX-related questions, and ultimately coming up with some data to put on answers.

Any thoughts? Will the data be of any use to anyone?

I also realize that the demographics of the survey is important. But I could start at the college, and if it goes well, try other places.

Comment: I had this same idea a couple months back, but I haven't had the time to follow through with it yet.  I think it's a great idea.  Go for it!

Comment: Related: see if you can convince Intro to Statistics students to run these surveys for their final projects.

Comment: I agree with @JessicaYang , it's always better to have others do your work for you.

Comment: Doing it "live" seems very time intensive for both the surveyor and the respondent.  This would make a great Captcha (similar to what they do now with OCR's of books. They show you one sort of known "challenge) paired with (essentially) a tiny Mechanical Turk problem ("what word is this") you could do the same with the icons.

Comment: Better yet, some of these can be kept going for years. The hamburger might not be commonly known right now, but might be next year. Or the year after that. Etc. Ideal for teachers as they can use it again next year!